# Is there a way, using javascript, to detect if there are multiple monitors connected to the device?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to tell if a device is connected to more than one monitor?
I looked up everywhere but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: javascript is a client web language why do you not use a system language like shell or bash or dos .... which is more for these kind of action ?

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @jeremy-denis I would assume this is for a webapp feature. A shell won't help there. (But then the question doesn't say anything like that)

Comment: I didn't find the answer I needed anywhere on StackOverflow, so responding late to the several related threads here. The solution is, first, check for second display with `window.screen.isExtended`. Then `await window.getScreenDetails()`, which returns an object that includes an array of screens. 

Very thorough explanation here: https://web.dev/multi-screen-window-placement/